# Через что реализовать вывод БД SQLite3 на C?

Tags: c, база-данных, sqlite3

При запросе SELECT * FROM CSVFILE WHERE content MATCH ‘s’; программа выводит данные, но сам вывод никак не прописан.
То есть, я через SQLite3_exec ввожу эту команду и, после ее выполнения, сразу выводятся данные, но не таким образом, как я хочу.

Выводит так: «SERIALNUMBER = 1COMPANYNAME = namDESCRIPTION = something”

Хочется, чтобы выводилось только то, что после знака «=», а не так, как сейчас.
На языке С.

Comment: а может покажете как именно написан код?

Comment: buffer[300]; int rc;                                               Sprintf(buffer, “SELECT * FROM csvfile WHERE COMPANYNAME MATCH ‘%s’;”, compname);                rc = sqlite3_exec(db, buffer, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

Comment: Нажмите линк `править`, и поместите код в свое сообщение.

Comment: @AnatoliiIvanov У Вас там есть callback функция. Она собственно и делает вывод. Она вызывается на каждую строку.

Comment: Да, сделал через call back, совсем забыл, спасибо!